# Distribution of stochastic integral to stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion, and let $H$ be a continuous adapted process with $\int_0^\infty H_s^2ds=\infty$. For $\sigma>0$, let $T_\sigma=\inf\{t\geq0:\int_0^tH_s^2ds>\sigma^2\}$. Find the distribution of the random variable $$X_\sigma=\int_0^{T_\sigma}H_sdB_s.$$ I really don't know where to start with this one, any hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks! I am told that if I use Dubin-Schwarz I have to prove it (which implies to me that I don't have to use Dubin-Schwarz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given some real number $\lambda$, you may introduce the exponential local martingale defined by
$$M_t := \exp\Big(i\int_0^t H_s \mathrm{d}B_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t H_s^2 \mathrm{d}s\Big).$$
Ito calculus (or your lecture) shows that $M$ is actually a local martingale.

You have $M_t \in [0,e^{\sigma^2}]$ for $t \in [0,T_\sigma]$, so Doob optional stopping theorem applies to $0$ and $T_\sigma$. In particular, $E[M_{T_\sigma}] = E[M_0] = 1$.

You derive the characteristic function of $X_\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response - it led me down the (hopefully correct) path of deriving the moment-generating function. In our lecture courses though, the exponential martingale was defined without an imaginary unit, which is why the moment-generating function was the one I ended up with.

Comment: @verygoodbloke If you take $exp(\int HdB_s - (1/2) H_s^2 ds)$, you do not have a good bound at $T_\sigma$ to ensure that you may apply Doob stopping time theorem.

Comment: I think that, defining $M_t=\int_0^tH_sdB_s$ with $[M]_t=\int_0^tH_s^2ds$, we have that the quadratic variation of the stopped process, $[M^{T_\sigma}]$, is uniformly bounded, and so the exponential martingale $\mathcal{E}(M^{T_\sigma}):=\exp(M^{T_\sigma}-(1/2)[M^{T_\sigma}])$ is uniformly integrable (by a result we have been given in lectures), and thus we can use the stopping theorem for any stopping time (and $T_\sigma$ is almost surely finite so $M_{T_\sigma}^{T_\sigma}$ is well defined).

Comment: @verygoodbloke Ah, all right. I did not remember this result.